# Simple IF STATEMENT on excel never works

Tags: excel, if-statement

For the first time i was trying to use the IF statement on excel, and it seemed really simple to use, but for some reason even the most basic statement never works.

Example : =IF(A3=1;"Yes";"No") give no result as shown as #NOM?

I checked my regional settigns and my separator is ";", no doubt of it.
Anyone have an idea ?

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyGnk.png)

Comment: So, had to change the ; to , but works perfectly on mine, gives Yes when A3=1 and No when A3=2

Comment: Have you tested **really** simple: =if(true;"Yes";"No") and =if(false;"Yes";"No") results in order Yes then No.

Comment: thnaks for the hint but both =if(true;"Yes";"No") and =if(false;"Yes";"No") gives the same results as before : #NOM?
I guess something is wrong with my excel parameters

Comment: Then you have to check things like language, is excel working in English?

Comment: Usually excel makes function suggestions as you start typing in the formula bar - did you not see the suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using french Excel?
Then you have to use `SI` instead of `IF`.

This page helps to translate the formulas: https://fr.excel-translator.de/

Comment: Yes iam and you completly resolved the problem, wouldn't have figured out it was language based.
Thanks a lot mate !